# Java For Loop not outputting How (I think) it should

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have no clue how I would research this otherwise, so here this is. I'm trying to create a program that will "flip bits", e.g. the string "00110011" would return "11001100". I tried to make a for loop to output the individual characters so see if getting the characters would work in this way, but it stops without outputting the characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bitsList = "01010101";
    char[] sepBits = bitsList.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Array'd");
    int num = bitsList.length();
    System.out.println("Got length");
    for (int count = 0; count == num;) {
                System.out.println(sepBits[count]);
                System.out.println("Outputted " + sepBits[count]);  
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think condition in `for` loop decides about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never go in your for loop because `count` is `0` and `num` is `8` (length of `"01010101"`). Therefore `count == num` evaluates to `false` and the for loop is not entered.

Try to replace your for loop with:

```
for (int count = 0 ; count < num ; count++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No worries. I hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable count is not equal to the variable num so the for loop never triggers. I think you are looking for <= not ==. Also you never change the count so the loop will just keep printing the same spot over and over even if you do change this.

Answer (score 0):

this might work for you

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String bitsList = "01010101";
    char[] sepBits = bitsList.toCharArray();
    int num = bitsList.length();

    for ( int i = num - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
        System.out.println("Outputted " + sepBits[i]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: This just reverses the string. His example is a bit ambiguous, but I think he is asking how to flip the bits, i.e. 0->1, 1->0.